# Google Analytics — Organic Search Traffic '(not provided)'

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine, keyword

I keep seeing

> (not provided)

under my

> Keywords

section so I'm unable to see what people are searching for when Googling my website.

I had a friend say for me to click 'Search Engine Optimisaion > Queries' in Analytics and then link it to Google Webmaster Tools.

I did this a few days ago but I'm still getting the '(not provided)' problem.

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming - this really belongs to webmasters.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I originally thought it might have been, but there appeared to be more Analytics questions in this forum than the Webmasters one

Comment: What should go here is the implementation stuff, everything that involves code. Configuration/technical background is a better fit for webmasters.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ah yes I see what you mean! Is there a way I can switch it to the other forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword (not provided) occurs for all Google searches now.  It only affects the organic results, not the paid.  It works by directing traffic through a redirect that strips off the keyword parameter, but keeps the other referrer information, so you at least still know it is coming from Google search.

You can't get rid of (not provided) appearing in analytics reports, and what your friend suggests is to instead link to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?pli=1), to see those reports (Which don't rely on Google Analytics), but comes straight from Google.  You could login and see those reports in more detail if you just set them up and login there.

The Google Analytics hookup isn't that useful, as you can't link the keywords to other Google Analytics metrics or dimensions - its just a straight import there for convenience if nothing else.

What may be useful to get some kind information is to use the landing page dimension in the keyword reports.  Select secondary dimension, then landing page and you will at least see where organic search has landed, and get some idea on what keywords they came from by looking at the title tag of that page.

Comment: thanks, had no idea I could get all this info from Webmaster Tools... looks really detailed!

Answer (score 1):

What you did was connecting the Search Console to Analytics. Here you get the Search Console Analytics Data in Google Analytics, but under a new Tab:

[image]

The Problem here is, that you don´t see the behavioural and transaction-Metrics for this Keywords (you even don´t see which Keyword rankt to which page).

As other mentioned the Problem is here Google Secure Search Update in 2011. Also Bing started 2015 to deliver the search results in https so you get less and less Keywords here.

There are some workarounds with filters for this https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/. But this are just "workarounds".

To get a idea of the Keywords a User googled to come to my pages i use https://keyword-hero.com/. They match the Keywords quite well. I test it now since ca. 3 weeks and it looks like this:
[image]

You can also use the Search Console itself to get an idea of the Keywords user googled, i thinks its the best source for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security thing.

If the search came from SSL Search on https://www.google.com Note the HTTPS not HTTP then the data is not shown to you.  Google stores it as (Not provided).   Webmaster toosl should be set up the same as this is a Google thing.

Google Analytics blog post : [Making search more secure: Accessing search query data in Google Analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.dk/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html)

The following is directly from Googles official blog:  [Making Search more Secure](http://googleblog.blogspot.dk/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html)

> As search becomes an increasingly customized experience, we recognize
>   the growing importance of protecting the personalized search results
>   we deliver. As a result, we’re enhancing our default search experience
>   for signed-in users. Over the next few weeks, many of you will find
>   yourselves redirected to https://www.google.com (note the extra “s”)
>   when you’re signed in to your Google Account. This change encrypts
>   your search queries and Google’s results page. This is especially
>   important when you’re using an unsecured Internet connection, such as
>   a WiFi hotspot in an Internet cafe. You can also navigate to
>   https://www.google.com directly if you’re signed out or if you don’t
>   have a Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the other answers, Google intentionally discontinued providing keywords when someone is referred from their search engine to a result page for privacy reasons.

There is no way around this within Google Analytics. There are some other methods for best guess using Webmaster Tools as also mentioned.

Another option is to use a tool that helps to match up keywords, landing pages and search volume. One such tool is provided by Authority Labs. There's probably some other providers too, this is just the one I know and use.

You can see exactly how Authority Labs works in this YouTube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72mLFFTAMpw